# NextJs: Type declaration for images imported from public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Can I know the what is the type declaration for images that are imported from public folder in nextjs.

I created a file called data in utils folder. Inside data file I imported the images from public folder and created a array of objects with keys like tile, desc, image.

For eg
`const users = [ { avatar: img1, name: "some name", age: 12, }, { avatar: img2, name: "some name", age: 14, } ]`

when i gave type for users obj it is showing an error of
`Types of property 'img' are incompatible. Type 'StaticImageData' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLImageElement': align, alt, border, complete, and 306 more.ts(2322)`

Can some one tell me the exact type for images imported from public folder and used it in array of objects

I tried to change the staticimagetype but it is unable to find

```
// data.ts file

export const SuccessStoriesCardData= [
    {
      title: "Some title",
      content: "some content",
      img:img1
    },
   {
      title: "Some title",
      content: "some content",
      img:img2
    },
    {
      title: "Some title",
      content: "some content",
      img:img3
    },

  ]
```

img1, img2, img3 are imported from public folder

types

```
 export type DataType = {
img: HTMLImageElement; 
title: string;
desc: string;
```

}

When I gave this type to child component and import the data in the parent component and pass to child the above type error is coming

Comment: Hi! Can you make it a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Can show where and how you are using SuccessStoriesCardData?

Answer (score 0):

It is because most of imported images in nextjs has type `StaticImageData`.
Most of images:  `*.png, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.webp, *.avif, *.ico, *.bmp`.

See the [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/image-types/global.d.ts#L5) in Github

> ```js
> // this file is conditionally added/removed to next-env.d.ts 
> // if the static image import handling is enabled
>
> declare module '*.png' {   const content:
>   import('../dist/client/image').StaticImageData
>
>   export default content 
> }
> ...
> ```

Typescript is trying to tell you that the correct type is `StaticImageData`.

You should update the type of `img` to `StaticImageData`.

```js
export type DataType = {
   img: StaticImageData; /* Use StaticImageData instead of HTMLImageElement */
   title: string;
   desc: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you import an image from a public folder, those images are parsed by the compiler as an object of type `StaticImageData` with all the necessary details of that image. They are not imported as components or HTML elements. This is why when you try to assign them to `avatar` property which has a type of `HTMLImageElement`, typescript gives you are type mismatch error. You can avoid this by using imported image data as src for `Image` component:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import UserImage from '../public/images/user.jpeg'

interface User {
  image: StaticImageData;
  name: string;
}

const users: User[] = [
  {
     image: UserImage
     name: "John"
  },
  {
     image: UserImage
     name: "Alen"
  }
]

export default function Users() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        users.map((user, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
              <Image src={user.image} alt={user.name} width={100} height={100}/>
              <h3>{user.name}</h3>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can learn more about Next.js static file serving [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) and Next Image [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image).